# How to print word document after edit it

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

i need to know how to print word file from windows form application after edit it

i used this cod to save my document

```
    DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("This message to confirm the data", "Data Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;

            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
           string pathTwo = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = "MMVA" + "(" + txt_Vname.Text + ")" + CustomFormatsave() + ".docx";
            saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".docx";
            saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = false;
            saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;

            //  saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                CreateWordDocument(pathTwo + @"\MMVA Template .docx", saveFileDialog1.FileName);

            }
```

after save my document  i need to print it 
what i can do ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to launch the file with the Print Verb. For example:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
info.Verb = "Print";
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start(info);
```

The other option is to use the Office SDK.

Comment: Worked , But it showed one page form my word and it opened in one note

Comment: It sounds like your default printer is set to 'OneNote'. Change your default printer to a real printer.

Comment: When you print from a real printer is will print all pages